# pandas: how to pivot a table with defined levels

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

My case is slightly different to what I have found so far online. I would like to pivot a pandas dataframe with a specific levels in the header. The pivot_table function requires values to be numeric, and the pandas.pivot function does not seem to do exactly what I want.

This is the starting code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'session':['2017', '2018','2017','2018','2017','2018'], 'domain':['network', 'network', 'facility', 'facility', 'access', 'access'], 'vendor':['vendorA', 'vendorA', 'vendorB','vendorB','vendorB','vendorB'], 'cost':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})
print df.to_string()
   cost    domain session   vendor
0    10   network    2017  vendorA
1    20   network    2018  vendorA
2    30  facility    2017  vendorB
3    40  facility    2018  vendorB
4    50    access    2017  vendorB
5    60    access    2018  vendorB
```

What I am after is something like that, where the first column level has only the 'domain' values, the 2nd column level the 'vendor' and 'cost' for each domain per 'session':

```
domain   network        facility       access 
session  vendor   cost  vendor   cost  vendor   cost
2017     vendorA  10    vendorB  30    vendorB  50
2018     vendorA  20    vendorB  40    vendorB  60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape, then [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) in `MultiIndex` in columns and last sort them by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['session','domain'])
        .unstack()
        .swaplevel(0,1,1)
        .sort_index(1, ascending=False)
print (df1)
domain   network      facility        access     
          vendor cost   vendor cost   vendor cost
session                                          
2017     vendorA   10  vendorB   30  vendorB   50
2018     vendorA   20  vendorB   40  vendorB   60
```

Alternatively use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='session',columns='domain')
        .swaplevel(0,1,1)
        .sort_index(1, ascending=False)
print (df1)
domain   network      facility        access     
          vendor cost   vendor cost   vendor cost
session                                          
2017     vendorA   10  vendorB   30  vendorB   50
2018     vendorA   20  vendorB   40  vendorB   60
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that @jezrael, this is exactly what I wanted. Out of curiosity, for each domain, what do I need to if I want to have vendor first and then cost columns?

Comment: I edit solution and add `.sort_index(1, ascending=False)` instead `.sort_index(1)`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that @jezrael, I learned something new today :)!